# ¿Cómo incluir archivos en php de diferentes rutas?

Tags: php, rutas

Espero que anden bien!
Acudo a su sabiduría para el siguiente problemita que estoy teniendo.

Estoy armando un proyecto en .php / mysql y tengo alrededor de 30 paginas todas en la carpeta raíz.
Me gustaría separarlas por las secciones a las que corresponden, pero tengo problemas con las rutas que hay dentro de otras paginas que incluyo. Dejo el ejemplo de estructura y mi problema.

```
Proyecto
    index.php
    head.php (incluuye style/styles.css)
    footer.php

    dba
            conn.php

    styles
            style.css

    reportes
            reportes.php
            nuevo-reporte.php

    crear-reportes
            crear-reporte.php
            editar-reporte.php
```

En el archivo reportes.php utilizo

```
include ('head.php');
```

Invoca correctamente el contenido de head, pero no me trae el archivo style.css, lo mismo pasa con otros archivos php que invocan otros archivos.

Podrán indicarme cual es el código correcto a utilizar para poder llamar archivos sin importar su ruta?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo `head.php` se puede usar la URL completa al archivo css:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Proyecto/styles/style.css">
```

o también es válido:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Proyecto/styles/style.css">
```

Si el `index.php` está en la raíz del servidor web (`http://localhost/index.php`) se puede usar

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
```